# Deluge tray icon is not clickable in KDE since 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde, deluge

In Kubuntu 11.10 I could click the tray icon and deluge's window would show, but now on 12.04, nothing happens. Only the right click works, and it shows the context menu, but there are no icons. Also it doesn't show the tooltip with Download/Upload statistics when I hover the mouse on its tray icon.

Does anyone know how to make deluge respond to clicking its tray button with the left button of the mouse?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the application indicator which is default now for Ubuntu and as with all indicators there are no right-click or tooltip options.

The previous functionality which you are referring to is from the older *systray* which can be reverted-to in `Preferences -> Interface` by un-checking `Enable Application Indicator`.

There is a [forum post](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=37229) where this was discussed in a bit more detail.

Comment: In the forum post it looks (from the screenshot at least) that they're talking about GNOME. My problem happens on KDE, however.

Comment: Have you tried changing the setting? The screenshot you provided is the indicator (i.e. not systray) which means you have the library installed in Kubuntu for it to be enabled.